# What do the progress bar lines mean?

Tags: nimble-quest

The bar on top shows the progress in the stage you are in. It gradually fills up as you kill monsters and the stage is finished when it is completely filled up. However, I noticed that there are lines/divisions in the progress bar in some stages. What do they signify?

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: I've also noticed that this bar isn't fixed. Sometimes it's closer to the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the high score marker....

Comment: I suspected that as well.

Comment: I think this is indeed the case.

Comment: That's a little inaccurate; It represents the farthest you've progressed in the game.  When you make it past this point and then die, the bar will then be redrawn at the point in which you died.  Your gem & kill high scores are not represented on this screen.

Comment: @CurtisTasker You may want to elaborate your comment as an answer instead.